# Open link in safari on facebook webview

Tags: ios, facebook, webview, deeplink

I host a html page with button to open a link in new tab .

Click Here

```
            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');">Google</a>

I want to open html page on the click on a button in facebook web view.
```

IF i try to give href or window.open to a link of html page. The page does not open in safari . .

How can i achieve it in third party browser.

Comment: I have tried using href and window.open still not able to achieve that.Just need to open an url in safari on click of button in facebook webview

Comment: You can’t. The app decides how links are handled. If the user has set it to open links in the in-app browser, then that’s what happens.